# Date formats for Americans

Tags: dates

Do Americans find a date such as 11 Apr 2012 more readable than the ISO format 2012-04-11? The reason I ask is that there are many situations where we do not have access to the locale, and even if we do there are often no locale-sensitive formatting functions that we can use.

Answer (score 6):

I think the ISO format (2012-04-11) will be slightly more jarring than 11 Apr 2012. However, if you're using numeric months, that might be a good thing. I suspect most Americans will associate 11-4-2012 with the 4th of November. The ISO format might make us pause, but it won't be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

The U.S. military uses the 11 Apr 2012 format (`DD MMM YYYY`, or `DD MMM YY`), so as to avoid ambiguities between 4 Nov and 11 Apr (4/11 and 11/4, not necessarily respectively, depending on where you reside).

The format is more uncommon outside of military correspondence, but I don't think anyone would tell you that such a date is "less readable" – maybe "less familiar."

Comment: Isn't `DD MMM YY` potentially almost as ambigious as `DD/MM/YY`? Take `11 Apr 12` for example; in ISO 8601 parlace, is that equal to 2011-04-12 or 2012-04-11? `DD MMM YYYY` is pretty hard to misread: `11 Apr 2012` is clearly the same day as `2012-04-11` (assuming of course that you are familiar with the ISO 8601 date format).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling 'MMM' implies that you spell out the 3letter abbrev for the month. 'MM' is the number which does cause problems

Comment: @mgb, the problem that I see is not the month (see my example `DD MMM YY` to `11 Apr 12`), but the potential for ambiguity between a two-digit day (`DD`) and two-digit year (`YY`).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - OK, although spelled out like this would generally mean year last as in an ISO format date

Answer (score 3):

American date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` but you are talking about `dd/MMM/yyyy` which doesn't match with American date format.